# Generating HTML output from criterion

Tags: haskell, haskell-criterion

There is a nice example of HTML output from [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) at http://bos.github.com/criterion/.

Which command line option is used to generate this output?

An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9731244/165544) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730166/capabilities-of-criterion) asserts that this output exits, but it does not seem to show up in the command line options when using `--help`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you just want html output, then `yourBench -o yourReport.html` will generate some perfectly reasonable output. If you want to use your own template, look at the templates/report.tpl example in the distribution and use the `-t` option.

Comment: Nice! I just skipped the, for me, unknown `.tpl` extension, but now I have learnt about the interesting library [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) with Haskell bindings as [hastache](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hastache-0.3.3).

Answer (score 6):

Sorry I didn't get around to your comment-question.

The answer Jedai gives is right - just use `-o`.   For example, here is a line from one of my Makefiles for running benchmarks using `defaultMain` from Criterion:

```
./Bench -g -u Bench.csv -o Bench.html -s $(SAMPLES)
```

Breaking that down, it says:

```
-g    run GC between each sample
-u    output CSV data to the given file
-o    output HTML data to the given file
-s    collect this many samples
```

Comment: Thanks for the -g option that did a great job for me and I got rid of many inconsistencies when using criterion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you just pass the template as a command line option, and then it populates it. If the template happens to be an html template, then you've generated html.

See the source here: https://github.com/bos/criterion

Comment: I have looked at the source code, but I cannot find it. How do you pass "the template" as a command line option?

Comment: @danr If --help isn't telling you (and it should) then just see the source for [Main.hs](https://github.com/bos/criterion/blob/master/Criterion/Main.hs) and search for `defaultOptions` or `template`.  you should see the `-t` option (which is just `t` in the options list).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson : Yes, thank you, I just didn't associate "template" with "HTML Output". Maybe this association should be obvious, but it isn't for me.